# How can I write this complex query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get the following complex query written in elasticsearch

```
select username, count(id), 
  concat(YEAR(postedtime),'-',MONTH(postedtime),'-',DAY(postedtime),' ',HOUR(postedtime)) 
from table 
where username in ("user1", "user2", "user3") 
group by username, 
  concat(YEAR(postedtime),'-',MONTH(postedtime),'-',DAY(postedtime),' ',HOUR(postedtime));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a query which should get you started - some notes:

- Counts are returned automatically and don't need to be explicitly
  requested.
- The `"size":0` prevents the documents being returned -
  you'll only see the aggregation.
- The dates returned will be in epoch
  format.
- You could replace the `query_string` with a `terms` query or
  even use a filter instead - it will depend on your requirements.
- there are 2 levels of aggregation, the first by username the 2nd by date buckets.

the code:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/table/_search?pretty' -d '{
 "size": 0,
 "query":{
    "query_string": { "query":"user1 OR user2 OR user3", "fields": ["username"]}
   },
 "aggs" : {
    "username_agg" : {
      "terms": {"field" : "username"},
      "aggs" : {
          "date_agg": { 
            "date_histogram" : { "field" : "postedtime", "interval" : "hour" } 
          }
       }
    }
  }
}'
```